# rm -r: exclude certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

**The problem**

I have a directory structure, e. g. something like this (here trailing slashes represent folders):

```
./A
./B/A/A
./B/A/B
./B/B/
./B/C
./C/
```

And I need to recursively remove everything except some files and directories:

```
./A
./B/A
```

After executing the command/script I'm searching for, I want to get the following hierarchy remaining:

```
./A
./B/A/A
./B/A/B
```

**The attempted solution**

I tried to use `find` (`-print` is a placeholder):

```
find \( -path ./A -or -path ./B/A \) -prune -or -print
```

This does not work because it removes parent directories of entries in the "do not touch" list:

```
$ find \( -path ./A -or -path ./B/A \) -prune -or -print
.
./B
./B/B
./B/C
./C
```

Especially, this removes `./B` while I need to keep `./B/A`. Heck, it removes current directory, after all.

I want to avoid recursive invocations (i. e. `find -exec something-that-calls-find.sh`) since the directory lists I'll be handling are quite big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to use a regular expression to match the paths

- `./B/A`
- `./B/A/A`
- `./B/A/B`
- `./B/A/B/C`
- et cetera

So, the following will match `./A` or anything below the `./B/A` folder, including it. I added a `\` to make the command more readable. Also note that this only works with GNU `find`, i.e. not on BSD `find`.

```
find -depth -regextype posix-extended -mindepth 1 \
! \( -path "./A" -or -regex "\./B(/A(/.*)?)?" \)
```

To explain the regex: The `/.*` matches anything under the `A` directory. You need the slash here because otherwise a directory called `AB` would have been matched too. This previous pattern can appear zero times (for the directory `A`) or once (for anything below `A`), that's why we need the `?`. Since we don't want to delete `B`, the part after it can occur zero or once (`?`).

Since there's a negation (`!`), the `find` command would match:

```
./B/B
./B/C
./C
```

You could then add the `-exec rm -rf {}`  option to remove those files and folders. We need the `-depth` option to start with the deepest one though, so as not to try and remove folders that don't exist anymore.

Comment: Here is why it will not work: it will try to remove `./B`, and thus will remove `./B/A` despite it is in the "ignore" list.

Comment: True, I totally missed that. I updated my regex.

Comment: Then yes, it seems to work and seems scriptable.
However,
1) it's better to use `-exec rm -rf {} \; -prune` and remove `.*` part of the regex, at least performance-wise;
2) I've found an easier-to-script solution (no path->regex transformation); I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Cool, would be nice to see what you've come up with! I didn't have much time to improve and iterate on this.

Comment: done, and my solution is two functions vs. one line :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution to that.
**NOTE:** I'm not that much of a portability lover when it comes to shell and utilities, so it possibly heavily depends on Bash 4 and GNU find.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash

## given "a/b/c/d", prints "a/b/c", "a/b" and "a".
# $1...: pathes to process
function get_parent_directories() {
    local CURRENT_CHUNK

    for arg; do
        CURRENT_CHUNK="$arg"

        while true; do
            CURRENT_CHUNK="$(dirname "$arg")"
            [[ "$CURRENT_CHUNK" == "." ]] && break
            echo "$CURRENT_CHUNK"
        done
    done
}

## recursively removes all files in given directory, except given names.
# $1: target directory
# $2...: exceptions
function remove_recursive() {
    local DIR="$1"
    shift
    local EXCEPTIONS=( "$@" )

    # find all files in given directory...
    local FIND_ARGS=( find "$DIR" -mindepth 1 )

    # ...skipping all exceptions and below...
    for file in "${EXCEPTIONS[@]}"; do
        FIND_ARGS+=( -path "$file" -prune -or )
    done

    # ...and ignoring all parent directories of exceptions (to avoid removing "./B" when "./B/A" is an exception)...
    while read file; do
        FIND_ARGS+=( -path "$file" -or )
    done < <(get_parent_directories "${EXCEPTIONS[@]}" | sort -u)

    # ...and printing all remaining names, without their descendants (we're going to recursively remove these anyway).
    FIND_ARGS+=( -print0 -prune )

    "${FIND_ARGS[@]}" | xargs -r0 rm -r
}
```

**Explanation**

The resulting `find` command line is built as a chain of `-predicates -actions -or` sequences.

This means following: for each path, if `-predicates` succeed, do `-actions`, otherwise go on to the next sequence. Last element in the chain is just `-actions`, which is the default case.

Here, I'm doing `-prune` for all pathes directly found in `$EXCEPTIONS`. This stops `find` from descending beyond these names.

Next, I'm doing nothing for all parents of pathes in `$EXCEPTIONS`. We do not want to remove parent directories of exceptions, as the removal is recursive.

Finally, I'm feeding all remaining pathes (the default case) to `xargs rm -r`. This is just faster than `-exec rm -r {} \;` because only one `rm` will be spawned.

I also do `-prune` for them because there is no point in explicitly removing `./A/B/C` if we're going to remove `./A/B`.

**P. S.:** this ended up in my snippet library :)